# How to make some string as a word in HTML input textbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am involving a Web Chatting System. I have an `input` textbox and a list of name which allow the user to choose and input them to the textbox. Here is the zero CSS jsFiddle which allow the user to click the name and input in the textbox.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cw0ngxp3/)

```js
$(document).on('click','.tag-panel-contact-name', function(){
    let name = $(this).attr('value');
    $('#textbox').val(name);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wchat-tag-container" style="display: block;">
  <div class="wchat-tag-panel">
    <!-- Contact List for tag -->
    <div class="wchat-tag-panel-contact" data-member-id="123" title="123">
      <span class="tag-panel-contact-name" value="Jason">Jason</span>
    </div>
    <div class="wchat-tag-panel-contact" data-member-id="124" title="124">
      <span class="tag-panel-contact-name" value="bot2">bot2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="wchat-tag-panel-contact" data-member-id="127" title="127">
      <span class="tag-panel-contact-name" value="Kopi">Kopi</span>
    </div>
    <div class="wchat-tag-panel-contact" data-member-id="555" title="555">
      <span class="tag-panel-contact-name" value="Host here">Host here</span>
    </div>
    <div class="wchat-tag-panel-contact" data-member-id="60105653762" title="60105653762">
      <span class="tag-panel-contact-name" value="Kopi Bryant">Kopi Bryant</span>
    </div>
  
  </div>
</div>

<input type="text" id="textbox">
```

My current problem is I want to make the name as a text, so when the user intent to remove/backspace the name, I want it directly delete the whole name and not character by character.

And another problem, for the real situation it is allowed to choose multiple names and input them in the textbox. So I am storing those names in JSON format array and how can I detect when user remove the tag name? So that I dont store the wrong data in the array.

Comment: your js fiddle doesn't match the description of your problem.  also, post it as a snippet

Comment: I am sorry, the edit has made. I wish to simplify my question.

Comment: use combination of a div and opaque textbox and handle backspace on keydown event of input to remove the selected name if textbox is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample code I have created from your code that you can use. I will suggest put the name together with an @, for example @Kopi, that way you can identify the user. Check the code, did some changes in the existing structure. Not sure if that works with your use case. May show you the direction.

Now for your second question, see the line in the code console.log('word before cursor: ' + wbc);, that will show you the word thats getting deleted, you can use that to update your array

```js
$(document).on('click','.tag-panel-contact-name', function(){
let name = $(this).attr('valuetag');
  var existingval = $('#textbox').val();
  if( existingval )
 $('#textbox').val(existingval+' @'+name);
  else
   $('#textbox').val('@'+name);
});

$(document).on('keydown','#textbox', function(e){
  var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
if (code == 8 || code == 46) {
// backspace or delete key
// backspace is 8, delete is 

//console.log(getPos(e.target));
        
  let endingIndex = getPos(e.target);
  let startingIndex = endingIndex && endingIndex - 1;
  let value = e.target.isContentEditable ? e.target.innerHTML : e.target.value;
  let regex = /[ ]/;

  while (startingIndex) {
if (regex.test(value[startingIndex])) {
  ++startingIndex;
  break;
}
--startingIndex;
  }
  var wbc = value.substring(startingIndex, endingIndex);
  //console.log('word before cursor: ' + wbc);
if( wbc.indexOf("@") == 0 ) {
e.target.value = value.slice(0, startingIndex) + value.slice(endingIndex)
e.preventDefault();
  }
  }
   
});


function getPos(elt) {
if (elt.isContentEditable) {  // for contenteditable
    elt.focus();
    let _range = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    let range = _range.cloneRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(elt);
    range.setEnd(_range.endContainer, _range.endOffset)
    return range.toString().length;
} else {  // for texterea/input element
    return elt.selectionStart;
}
}

function setPos(elt, pos) {
if (elt.isContentEditable) {  // for contenteditable
    elt.target.focus();
    document.getSelection().collapse(elt.target, pos);
} else {  // for texterea/input element
    elt.target.setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wchat-tag-container" style="display: block;">
  <div class="wchat-tag-panel">
    <!-- Contact List for tag -->
    <div class="wchat-tag-panel-contact" data-member-id="123" title="123">
      <span class="tag-panel-contact-name" valuetag="Jason" value="Jason">Jason</span>
    </div>
    <div class="wchat-tag-panel-contact" data-member-id="124" title="124">
      <span class="tag-panel-contact-name" valuetag="bot2" value="bot2">bot2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="wchat-tag-panel-contact" data-member-id="127" title="127">
      <span class="tag-panel-contact-name" valuetag="Kopi" value="Kopi">Kopi</span>
    </div>
    <div class="wchat-tag-panel-contact" data-member-id="555" title="555">
      <span class="tag-panel-contact-name" valuetag="Hosthere" value="Host here">Host here</span>
    </div>
    <div class="wchat-tag-panel-contact" data-member-id="60105653762" title="60105653762">
      <span class="tag-panel-contact-name" valuetag="KopiBryant" value="Kopi Bryant">Kopi Bryant</span>
    </div>
  
  </div>
</div>

<input type="text" id="textbox">
```

Comment: this doesn't really answer the question now does it?

Comment: @DCR sorry, I see the second question I missed. I will update it.

Comment: thanks.. looks like this is what I want to achieve. Thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

why not just use a select box?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wchat-tag-container" style="display: block;">
  <div class="wchat-tag-panel">
  
  
  <select name="name" id="name" >
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="Jason">Jason</option>
  <option value="bot2">bot2</option>
  <option value="kobi">kobi</option>
  <option value="Host here">Host here</option>
  <option value="Kobi Bryant">Kobi Bryant</option>
</select>
```

although if you really want to do it the other way:

```js
var input = document.getElementById('textbox')
input.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) { 

if (event.keyCode == 8){
document.getElementById('textbox').value = ''
}

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wchat-tag-container" style="display: block;">
  <div class="wchat-tag-panel">
    <!-- Contact List for tag -->
    <div class="wchat-tag-panel-contact" data-member-id="123" title="123">
      <span class="tag-panel-contact-name" value="Jason">Jason</span>
    </div>
    <div class="wchat-tag-panel-contact" data-member-id="124" title="124">
      <span class="tag-panel-contact-name" value="bot2">bot2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="wchat-tag-panel-contact" data-member-id="127" title="127">
      <span class="tag-panel-contact-name" value="Kopi">Kopi</span>
    </div>
    <div class="wchat-tag-panel-contact" data-member-id="555" title="555">
      <span class="tag-panel-contact-name" value="Host here">Host here</span>
    </div>
    <div class="wchat-tag-panel-contact" data-member-id="60105653762" title="60105653762">
      <span class="tag-panel-contact-name" value="Kopi Bryant">Kopi Bryant</span>
    </div>
  
  </div>
</div>

<input type="text" id="textbox" >
```